# Why docker container on specific port return connection refused?

Tags: docker, connection, port, vps

I have a Linux VPS with docker installed, I ran an Nginx docker container on a specific port using flag **-p**, when I try connecting to it using *VPS_IP:PORT* always get *Connection_Refused*.

even using `curl http://localhost:PORT` return connection refused.

Except for port 80, every other port refuses to connect, though **ufw** is disabled.

docker container command I used:

`docker container run -d -it -p 83:83 --name container_name -v /home/.../:/container_path/ nginx`

Any thoughts on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think you have changed the server configuration to have nginx serve on port 83. If you want port 83 of the VPS to be used, do: `docker run -p 83:80 [...]`. This way, port 83 of the VPS will be mapped to port 80 of the nginx container. Docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct docker container command is :

```
docker container run -d -it -p 83:80 --name container_name -v /home/.../:/container_path/ nginx
```

Because Nginx docker image is listening on internal port 80